# DecimalFormat turning '-' into '?'

Tags: java, string, numbers, decimalformat

I have a software being run in different enviroments.
If I run on my machine the following code:

```
double s = -0.04374467357823164;
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println("Formatted: " + numberFormat.format(s));
```

The code outputs -0,043. However in one of the users machine the result is:
?0,043

He is running the following java version:

```
openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-16.0.2+7 (build 16.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-16.0.2+7 (build 16.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The java version on my machine is:

```
openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Both operating systems are Windows.

My question is why is the same code behaving different and how to do it so it always outputs -0,043.

Thanks for your time and I hope the question is well explained.

Comment: You don't specify a locale for your `DecimalFormat`, so it will use the platform default locale. It's possible that whatever locale that is uses a minus symbol that can't be output with whatever encoding you use to write this. Try using `Locale.ROOT` if you want "C-style" or "neutral" number formats.

Answer (score 0):

DecimalFormat in the form that you used is depending on the locale set of the machine running the code, so having two different machines can generate different behaviours.

You can solve this problem in two ways:

- setting a specific Locale
- setting a specific character as decimal separator

**Setting a specific `Locale`**

You can set a `Locale` programmatically using the method [`Locale.setLocale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale)):

> Sets the default locale for this instance of the Java Virtual Machine.

You can also set the `Locale` passing arguments to the jvm as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s1809settingthejavavirtualmachineloca01.html)

**Defining a specific character as decimal separator**

When you create the `DecimalFormat` use the constructor [`DecimalFormat(String pattern, DecimalFormatSymbols symbols)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols)) that let you:

> **Creates a DecimalFormat using the given** pattern and **symbols**. Use this constructor when you need to completely customize the behavior of the format.